# Взаимосвязь меню и контента

Tags: css, wordpress

Меню сделано через сайдбар, оно подключено выше контента.

Когда я открываю одну из вкладок (выпадающий список), то контент спускается вниз. Ну и если закрою вкладку, то вернётся обратно.

Можно ли это как то исправить? Чтобы контент на месте оставался.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Народ требует код! и картинок...

Comment: @B.Denis а зачем тут код собсна?) Картинку прикрепил

Comment: чтобы быстрее решить проблему, скорее всего у всплывающего меню position:static, а надо position:absolute

Comment: еще z-index добавить что бы сверху всех блоков был

Comment: @B.Denis Меню сделана плагином , никаких позиций нет

Comment: ну значит плагин правьте ручками

Comment: @B.Denis Попробовал добавить z-index - безрезультатно

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49389/discussion-between-b-denis-and-).